# How to change number of columns in acm_proc template

Tags: two-column, acm

I am using sigproc paper template. It has two columns, how can I convert it to one column paper? (with the same font and other attributes)

Comment: I can't tell which class you are using but if it is like the `acmconf.cls` in texlive it has `\LoadClass[twocolumn]{article}` so forces twocolumn with no option to over-ride, you can always just copy the file to `myclass.cls` use `\documentclass{myclass}` and change `twocolumn` to `onecolumn` But the whole point of publisher styles is to force specific layout, by design they do not have the flexibility of generic classes like article

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use `acm_proc_article-sp.cls` format. I ended up removing the `\maketitle` and class tag.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Short answer?

Answer (score 1):

After `\maketitle` add `\onecolumn` in the next line. This also works if you are using `sig-alternate-05-2015.cls` (which is compatible with `acm_proc_article-sp.cls`) where your class definition looks like this: `\documentclass{sig-alternate-05-2015}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How is this answering the question of the OP? In the comments it is mentionend that the used class is `acm_proc_article-sp.cls` and not the one you mentionend. You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: These `cls` files are related. I should have said that that it works for current version of the `cls` file I mentioned, but if you try my suggestion using `acm_proc_article-sp` it works just the same. This way one can still keep the title section. I had the same question and found this fix, I thought I pass it along. Just trying to help others.